# how to embed the whole <body> to a created new div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to perform the sticky footer to a stand-for-a-long web project.
I'm required to create two top-level div and wrap up all the content inside of `<body>` into  'div-container', then to add 'div-footer' to the end of `<body>` or `<html>`
like

```
<body>
<div id='container'>
//all body 
</div>
<div id='footer'>
</div>
</body>
```

How can i do it with jQuery? i tried but failed with the code below (coz 'container' don't know where to append),

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    addStikyFooter();
});

function addStikyFooter() {
    $("<div id='container'></div>").append($('body'));
    var footerHtml = "<div id='footer'>i'm testing!/footer>";
    alert($('body').html());
}
```

Comment: If you need to select something with an id use the # character. $('#container').append('<p>some html</p>');, just like css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
    $("body").append("<div id='footer'></div>");
```

Append will add your code at the end, but within the specified element. So `$("body").append()` will add things within the body.

In your code it looks like you switched the order of the content and the element to append to, so your code should read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    addStikyFooter();
});

function addStikyFooter() {
    $("body").append("<div id='container'></div>");
    $("body").append("<div id='footer'>i'm testing!</div>");
}
```

[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/vSumY/)

Comment: hi, thanks, i updated my topic, please help check again, i first need to embed all the body content into a div-container. footer is okay for me. not a challenge.

Comment: I ever used the code you just posted, but 'alert($('body').html())',  shows div all appended to the end of body-content, so I thought i failed.. anyway, it works :)

Comment: You're welcome. Append() will add things at the end of but within the specified element, so the alert box here is showing everything that is now inside the body ==> http://jsfiddle.net/k9ybH/

Comment: ya.. that's it. it looks like just append to the end, but not embedding the body content.

Comment: hi, Perter, you there? I just found this kinda eventually turns out to be 
    <html>
    <div id='container'>
    <body>..</body> 
    </div>
    <div id='footer'>
    </div>
    </html>
not what I wanted.. this blocks horizontal-scrollbar, i don't know why

Please try here, http://jsfiddle.net/7szM4/1/

Comment: @Elaine - The code you linked is not doing what I described in my answer. It is very different. I edited it ==> http://jsfiddle.net/yq5FK/ . The edited code does do what I described in the answer - If you use Firebug, you can check that's true ==> http://i.imgur.com/pzwDc.jpg